# How to set wordpress to open up on localhost?

Tags: wordpress, iis, windows-server-2008-r2

I have an IIS server that will be used to run Wordpress. At the moment, my wordpress can be viewed from the url "www.example.com/myblog". Where do I change the settings such that when I got to "www.example.com" it will point it to the blog directly?

Do i change this in the IIS setting or in the wordpress settings?

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Using a pre-existing subdirectory install.

When using IIS, be sure to change the default document so it can see index.php with a higher priority.